# Given common probability density function $f(x, y) = e^{-(x+y)}$ where $0 \le x ,y < \infty$, calculate $P(X < Y)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

First time I'm getting to such question:

> Given common probability density function $f(x, y) = e^{-(x+y)}$ where $0 \le x ,y < \infty$, calculate $P(X < Y)$.

What is the way to approach such question? any help will be welcomed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to get a geometric feel for what the set $X<Y$ looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to integrate the pdf over the given area $X<Y$. This gives, for example,
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{y}f(x,y)dxdy
\end{equation}
Also, by symmetry, you can argue that the answer must be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks you :) Can you please explain why you set these integral bounds?

Comment: Well, assuming $Y$ is a certain value, we want $X$ to be lower. So now we integrate over all possible $X<Y$. Other possible bounds would have been $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}f(x,y)dydx$